R equivalent of MATLAB's pascal(n, 1) different column signs
I'm porting some MATLAB code to R and have come across this function:
pascal(4, 1)
which, according to the documentation, "returns the lower triangular Cholesky factor (up to the signs of the columns) of the Pascal matrix" and produces



1
0
0
0




1
-1
0
0


1
-2
1
0


1
-3
3
-1



I think the equivalent R code is
t(chol(pascal(4)))
which produces the same numbers, up to the column signs as anticipated by the MATLAB documentation:



1
0
0
0




1
1
0
0


1
2
1
0


1
3
3
1



What is the equivalent R code to produce the expected results with the correct column signs?

You can try pascal from package pracma
> library(pracma)

> pascal(4, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1   -1    0    0
[3,]    1   -2    1    0
[4,]    1   -3    3   -1

